# ours won't be simply "42."

Tags: word-meaning

What do you think "42" means?  Google offers "42, in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams, is the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything", calculated by a supercomputer named Deep Thought over a period of 7.5M years."

But what sense do you get at the glance of "42" without this Google explanation?

> *Why is there something rather than nothing?*
> *Why do we exist?*
> *Why this particular set of laws and not some other?*
>
> This is the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything. We shall attempt to answer it in this book. Unlike the answer given in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, **ours won't be simply "42."**

Source: The Grand Design by Stephen Hawking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence compares two answers:

- 'ours', which can be replaced with 'our answer', i.e. the one by the author of the book, Stephen Hawking; he's only one person but the plural could be referring to the team writing the book
- 'the answer given in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy'

All you can conclude grammatically from the sentence is that the first answer is something else than 42, and the second answer *is* 42. The double quotes make that even clearer. Without reading that book, or the Google excerpt you found, there's no deeper meaning to the 42. (I actually read the book, and even after that, I don't see any deeper meaning in 42. But that was probably intended by Douglas Adams, just as the question *itself* (to which "42." is the answer) is never revealed.)

Comment: It's a joke, surely. The computer was asked to find an answer to a deep philosophical question and, being 'only' a computer, could only come up with a meaningless number. Adams' work is sufficiently well-known for Prof. Hawking to make a humorous reference to it.